# Pass in bash terminal variables to a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, variables

If I am in a Linux terminal and I start setting variables such as export `AGE=45`.

Then I have a script to read user data from terminal variables and process it, is this possible to do?

```
IE:

user@linux$ export AGE=45

user@linux$ ./age.sh

#script asks for input

read -p "what is your age?" scriptAGE

#user inputs variable set in terminal

$AGE
```

#echo output

```
echo "your age is: " $scriptAGE"
```

#should say your age is: 45

Comment: Variables are not expanded in user input.

Comment: You have unmatched quotes in your `echo` command.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a **terminal variable**. `read` just assigns a string to your variable `scriptAGE`.

If this string contains some *$NAME* you want to expand, you **could** apply `eval` to it, but this is of course extremely dangerous because of possible code injection.

A safer way to do this is using `envsubst`, but this requires that the variables to be substituted must be **environment variables**. In your case, `AGE` is in the environment, so this condition is met.

In your case, you would have to do therefore a

```
envsubst <<<"$scriptAGE"
```

which would print on stdout the content of *scriptAGE* with all environment variables in it substituted.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not expanded in input, only in the script itself.

You could use `eval` to force it to process the variable value as shell syntax.

```
eval "echo 'your age is:' $scriptAGE"
```

But this will also process other shell syntax. If they enter `$AGE; rm *` it will say their age is 45 and then delete all their files.

Answer (score 0):

you could just do

```sh
age=$1
echo "Your age is $1"
```

where $1, $2, $3, .., $N are the passed arguments by order

And then run your script

```sh
bash script sh Noureldin
```

For more Info read this:

- [passing names args](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129391/passing-named-arguments-to-shell-scripts)